# c++ smart pointers for directx

Tags: c++, c++11, directx

I've recently been going through the process of replacing all my raw pointers with c++11 smart pointers, and now I'm finally done with the exception of my DirectX long pointers.

I'd like to get something along the lines of the below implemented:

```
std::shared_ptr<IDirect3D9> p_d3d;
p_d3d( Direct3DCreate9(D3D_SDK_VERSION), [](IDirect3D9 *p) {//smart pointer initialization(1)
        p->Release();
});
```

I'm getting the following error from visual studio:

> error : call of an object of a class type without appropriate
>   operator() or conversion functions to pointer-to-function type

I'd prefer to use std::unique_ptr or std::shared_ptr than CComPtr.
Any ideas on why this is happening and possible methods of implementation?

Comment: The initialization is done when you declare the variable.

Comment: The C++ smart pointers do not support the ref-counting semantics that COM objects rely on. You are well advised using the COM smart pointers.

Comment: having two competing reference counting schemes is not a good idea. in particular with your intended scheme the referred to object can be destroyed while you have a set of smart pointers to it. instead build your own COM smart pointer. if you're using the Boost library you can save some work by using `boost::intrusive_ptr` (if I recall its name correctly). unfortunately that building block was not adopted into the C++11 standard.

Comment: @cheers I do not see how myself.  The set of all shared_ptr can share one com reference count.  When they all go away, the last one releases it.  There is no more problem here than having a shared_ptr owned object that has a CComPtr member variable.

Comment: @Yakk: it's no problem calling `p->Release()` when `p` is a `std::shared_ptr` point to a COM object. Then you still have a pointer but no pointee. As I recall the ATL COM pointers\ fixes this by having `operator->` returning the pointer downcasted to an interface where `AddRef` and `Release` are private. Anyway that's how I do it. In addition to security, you also want your COM smart pointer to support certain COM things, such as casting to an interface.

Comment: @cheers sure.  They can also memcpy over what is pointed to.  Not much wrong with blocking it, but...

Comment: After going through all the comments and attempting various implementations, I've come to the conclusion that CComPtrs keep things simplest with minor need for change. Thank you for all the replies; they've helped a lot.

Comment: @dk123 what was the resolution for you here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be calling operator() on your shared_ptr.  That is not how you construct a shared_ptr.  Try using reset, or constructing the pointer on the same line as you declare the variable.

Be careful that the creation function you call gives you a pointer with a reference count of one.